# AtomicBoolean guard for not thread-safe data (volatile piggybacking)

Tags: java, concurrency

Is it safe to use `AtomicBoolean` as non-blocking lock for read and write access to not thread-safe data from multiple threads, using construction:

```
if (lock.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
  try {
    //Access non-volatile fields, non-atomic arrays and not thread-safe classes
  } finally {
    lock.set(false);
  }
} else {
  //Access denied, try again later or right now
}
```

The data is not accessible outside this construction. I'm almost sure it's safe because of volatile piggybacking effect. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The high-level consideration must be whether it safely precludes concurrent access to the critical ressource. This works as `AtomicBoolean` provides the necessary guarantees. As a rule of thump, the JMM is designed in a way that if you implement the high-level logic correctly, the low level things will be too.

Going more into detail as you do in your question, the `volatile` reads and writes preclude unintended re-ordering just as you expect (aka “piggybacking”).

You are basically doing what a `Lock` does too. A `ReentrantLock` will use an `int` rather than a `boolean`, and the `Lock`s  provide a waiting queue which a simple atomic variable does not.

The [`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html) shows how that logic (similar to yours) is implemented around one atomic `int` variable.

Comment: +1 this is guaranteed because "*The memory effects for accesses and updates of atomics generally follow the rules for volatiles.*" ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html)).

Comment: Yes, but even a volatile read at the entry of the block would be enough for the memory effect though it would not preclude the concurrent access. And the volatile write at the end of the block should not be forgotten.

Comment: I see now! I should change `AtomicBoolean` to `ReentrantLock` and invoke `tryLock()` and `unlock()` methods in my construction. Thank you!